# After executing git update-ref HEAD <commit id>, the commit file at HEAD does not update to the commit id I passed it

Tags: git

Maybe I'm not understanding git update-ref correctly, but I thought after running git update-ref HEAD , my text file at HEAD would update to the content of the commit id I passed it. For example, if the text file at HEAD has "Hi" inside, and I run the earlier command passing a commit id that has "Hello" inside its text file, wouldn't the HEAD now have the text file with "Hello" inside it? Instead, I'm still getting "Hi" when I open the file - however git log shows that the HEAD has updated to the "Hello" commit.

Comment: It will be easy to understand if you give me the contents of the file that will be helpful

Comment: It's literally two text files with "Hi" and "Hello". The HEAD is at "Hi" and when i run git update-ref "Hello", the Head now points at "Hello" but when i open the file, it shows "Hi".

Answer (score 0):

All `git update-ref` does is update the specified reference.  This has no effect on the work-tree.  The command you're using is behaving correctly, but you should not be using the command you're using.<sup>1</sup>

If you want to switch to some other commit, use `git checkout`, or (in Git 2.23 or later) `git switch`.

---

<sup>1</sup>`git update-ref` is a very low level command that is meant to be used by other Git commands, *after* they do all the *other* stuff you need to do in order to make such an update sensible.  In general, updating a ref tends to be the last, or second-to-last, step of various operations.